# Fable - Cannot get type info of generic parameter, please inline or inject a type resolver

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I'm trying to write a generic json decode function in fable. It seems to compile in FSharp but I get the error message for this code:

[using the Thoth.Json library and the Fetch library from Fable.PowerPack]

```
let autoDecoder<'a> (json:string) (value:obj) : Result<'a, Thoth.Json.Decode.DecoderError> =
    let tryDecode = Thoth.Json.Decode.Auto.fromString<'a>(json)
    let getDecoderError (str:string) : Thoth.Json.Decode.DecoderError = ( "Auto decode Error", Thoth.Json.Decode.FailMessage str) 
    Result.mapError getDecoderError tryDecode
```

error FABLE: Cannot get type info of generic parameter, please inline or inject a type resolver

I'm not sure how to fix this and haven't been able to find anything on google.

I want to be able to call the function like this in my update function in Fable Elmish:

```
let update (msg:Msg) (model:Model) =
    match msg with
..
    | OrStart ->
        let getData() = Fetch.fetchAs<ResultResponse>  "https://randomuser.me/api/" json.autoDecoder<ResultResponse> http.getHeaders
        model, Cmd.ofPromise getData () LoadedTypedData FetchError
```

How can I get fable to compile the autoDecoder<'a> function while keeping it generic?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Fable is telling you to use `inline` like this:

```
let inline autoDecoder<'a> (json:string) (value:obj) : Result<'a, Thoth.Json.Decode.DecoderError> =
    let tryDecode = Thoth.Json.Decode.Auto.fromString<'a>(json)
    let getDecoderError (str:string) : Thoth.Json.Decode.DecoderError = ( "Auto decode Error", Thoth.Json.Decode.FailMessage str) 
    Result.mapError getDecoderError tryDecode
```

That is because generic functions just like inline functions need to be instantiated for each call.

BTW, the `value` parameter is not being used.

You can also streamline the code like this:

```
let inline autoDecoder<'a> (json:string) : Result<'a, Thoth.Json.Decode.DecoderError> =
    Thoth.Json.Decode.Auto.fromString<'a> json
    |> Result.mapError (fun (str:string) ->  "Auto decode Error", Thoth.Json.Decode.FailMessage str)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what allowed me to compile for fable; the function itself though was not working - the json came through as an empty string and I've just used the other "answer" because I didn't have the time to figure out why

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to fable and I wasn't able to get it working, the fable compiler does not allow the auto decode without a specified type - fails here:

```
Thoth.Json.Decode.Auto.fromString<'a>(str, true)
```

But for anyone struggling with the fetch api in fable, this can be done with not too much boilerplate code. I couldn't get the promise to be generic, but a type specific implementation like getCustomers is quite succinct and I ended up doing something like this:

```
type Msg =
    | Start
    | LoadedCustomerData of Result<QueryDataForJson, string>
..

let getCustomers () = promise {
    let! response = Fetch.fetch "http://localhost:5000/spa/api/customers" http.getHeaders
    let! text = response.text()
    return Thoth.Json.Decode.Auto.fromString<QueryDataForJson>(text, true)
}
..
let update (msg:Msg) (model:Model) =
    match msg with
    | Start ->
        model, Cmd.ofPromise getCustomers () LoadedCustomerData FetchError
    | LoadedCustomerData resp ->
        match resp with
            | Ok qdj -> { model with gridData= queryDataFromJson qdj; message= "Loaded Customer Data"  }, Cmd.none
            | Error str -> { model with message = str }, Cmd.none
```